# How to force wineconsole to exit after program end and get ascii output to linux terminal?

Tags: linux, console, wine

I'm currently running windows application using this command line:

```
env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/winedotnet wineconsole --backend=curses app.exe 1.bin
```

However, this way has some drawbacks:

1. Wine does not close console until I press enter (normally, the console program exits after execution).
2. When I'm trying redirect output to the file, I receive the following (truncated):

```
^[[?1049h^[[22;0;0t^[[1;24r^[(B^[[m^[[4l^[[?7h^[[39;49m^[[?1h^[=^[[?12;25h^[[39;49m^[[37m^[[40m^[[H^[[2J^[(B^[[0;1m^[[37m^[[40m^[[J^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[[37m^[[40m^[[?25l^[[?12;25h^[]2;app.exe
```

The questions are:

- Is it possible to force wine exit after program end?
- How to redirect program output to file without the above control chars (only ascii and \r\n)?

Comment: same for me. Having similar question